# Adding subview to `UITableViewCell` is repeated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use custom edit actions then edit the row by `indexPath` after action is pressed

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewRowAction *DeleteButton = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
    {
      UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      UISwitch *Switch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:Switch];
    }];

 return @[DeleteButton];
}
```

This adds a `UISwitch` to the cell that pressed `Delete` action button, **However** it's being repeated every 12 rows or so; All indexpaths are different *(0-1)-(0-2)..etc*.

I personally believe this is caused because of the method used to grab the cell in this line
`UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: Are you using reusable cells?

Comment: No I'm not, Not quite sure if it's possible to use with `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`, Feel free to post an answer if possible

Comment: Why are you adding a subview during the delete action?

Comment: It's an additional button, but i left it as delete here to make it clear I'm using action swipe buttons.

Comment: I just tought that maybe if you were using reusable cells, you could be adding the switch to a cell that already had one, because it's reused

Comment: did you try this NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; ?

Comment: @T_77 I just did, It returns null. Because It's not a selected row, It's a swipe action for the cell and I already have access to the indexPath argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, cell's are re-used as cells scroll off the top of the screen and fresh cells scroll up from the bottom. Unless you have specifically opted out of this behavior, it would explain precisely what you're observing. If you set any property on a cell that is visible (be it the text on a label, or adding a subview as you're doing), those changes need to be un-done in order that when the cell is "re-used" or recycled, the modifications aren't still visible in a context you're not expecting or desiring.

One solution to this problem would be to use a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` instead of adding your switch subview to the standard `UITableViewCell`. You would give the custom subclass a property with a reference to the subview switch you're adding in the rowAction method. This reference gives you the ability to remove or hide it later.

You might consider making the switch a subview that is always present in your custom cell's `contentView`, but that is hidden or shown as needed by the action method.

In your subclass, you would override the `-prepareForReuse` method, and you would either remove or hide the subview from the custom cell's content view to prepare the cell to be presented in a fresh context (e.g. without the added switch when you are not expecting it.)

Create a custom cell subclass:

```
@interface SampleCellTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) UISwitch *aSwitch;

@end

@implementation SampleCellTableViewCell

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [[self aSwitch] removeFromSuperview];
    [self setaSwitch:nil];
}

@end
```

In your action method, assign the property:

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewRowAction *DeleteButton = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
    {
      SampleTableViewCell *cell = (SampleTableVieCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      UISwitch *switch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:switch];
      [cell setaSwitch:switch];
    }];

 return @[DeleteButton];
}
```

Comment: Would it work to make a verification of specific text inside that cell ? I.E : I added subview for a cell that has a label of text "foo", Can i prevent repeating on other cells by verifying it's foo ( Even though not a very reliable solution but it would mostly work for my case )

Comment: Well, you could approach it that way, but you still need a hook to perform the logic of show/don't show the switch. This hook could be in -prepareForReuse, or you could also do it in the tableview's -cellForRowAtIndexPath, but either way you need a reference to that specific subview you want hidden or shown. What condition you use to determine if it should be shown or hidden isn't really the issue, it's how you go about hiding or showing it.

Comment: Can you also please add an example for your solution ? It's nearly pretty much what I'm saying but would like to see an example if possible

Comment: After several attempts, The addsubview is only executed once, By adding an `NSLog` before adding the subview to confirm this. It supposed to be repeated everytime i scroll through the cell that has it repeated, However It's not.

It looks like it's pre-added to several cells not sure why. Am i right here ?